# Add a description to array of images using angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, image, object

I need to add a description to each image in the below array of images, which is found in this object:

```
[
  {
    "id": "Movie Poster Remixes",
    "name": "HULK Remix",
    "practices": ["Graphics", "Sketching", "Artwork", "Vector Manipulation"],
    "technology": ["Inkscape", "Photoshop"],
    "time": "3 Weeks",
    "description": "A series of poster remixes I have one over the past couple of years. I tend to spend any free time working on some graphical artwork which tends to be printed off & framed in my house.",
    "images": [
        "../assets/img/details/15/1.jpg",
        "../assets/img/details/15/2.jpg",
        "../assets/img/details/15/3.jpg",
        "../assets/img/details/15/4.jpg"
    ],
    "header": "../assets/img/paramount-logo.svg",
    "behance": "https://www.behance.net/gallery/26358303/Avengers-Hulk-Desktop-WallPaper-Design"
  }
]
```

I can't seem to get this work. The images display in the view, but am unable to see how to add a description.

Any help would be much appreciated. TIA.

*this is how I am currently accessing the object in my controller and binding certain key values to the scope.*

```
$http.get('app/resources/v1/projects/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').success(function (details) {

        $scope.details = details;
        angular.forEach($scope.details, function (detail) {
            $scope.header = detail.header;
            $scope.intro = detail.id;
        });
```

*this is the html from the view to see how I am then exposing it*

```
           <div ng-repeat="image in detail.images">
                <img class="img-responsive presentation" ng-src="{{ image.path }}" />
                <table class="like-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a ng-click="likeCount = likeCount + 1">
                                <img class="presentation like" ng-src="{{ like }}" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>Like: </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong> {{ likeCount }}</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a ng-click="shareCount = shareCount + 1">
                                <img class="presentation like" ng-src="{{ share }}" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>Share: </td>
                        <td>
                            <strong> {{ shareCount }}</strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you showed us the relevant bit of the view HTML code, so we can have a better understanding of your problem and how you want the descriptions to show up. It is unclear to me if it is the data binding (ie passing data to the view) you are having trouble with, since you mention that the images do display. Also, are you using Angular 1.x or Angular2?

Comment: I've added in the key components. I'm pretty sure it is the construction of my json object at this time, not the html. I may need to alter some of the ways in which I am binding - but not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** You can't access the image paths as you did when images was just an array. It may be an issue with how you're setting up your json files and/or how you're performing the ng-repeat. Throw some console logs in your code and make sure that the variable $scope.details is as you would expect.

*NOTE:* I would consider keeping any data that follows this same structure, i.e. has the same keys, in one JSON file. That makes your app more efficient in that you make a single $http.get request upon page load and assign the response to $scope.details. You don't have to make a separate $http.get request for json files that have a similar structure - why not get it all from the start?

```
<div ng-repeat="image in detail.images">
   <img class="img-responsive presentation" ng-src="{{ image.path }}" />
      <table class="like-table">
         ...
```

If you are trying to add a description to each image in the images array, I would suggest changing the array **images** to an **array of objects**. So your data object would look like this (notice the change to the images array):

```js
[
  {
    "id": "Movie Poster Remixes",
    "name": "HULK Remix",
    "practices": ["Graphics", "Sketching", "Artwork", "Vector Manipulation"],
    "technology": ["Inkscape", "Photoshop"],
    "time": "3 Weeks",
    "description": "A series of poster remixes I have one over the past couple of years. I tend to spend any free time working on some graphical artwork which tends to be printed off & framed in my house.",
    "images": [
        { 
          "url": "../assets/img/details/15/1.jpg",
          "desc": "Description 1"
        },
        { 
          "url": "../assets/img/details/15/2.jpg",
          "desc": "Description 2"
        },
        { 
          "url": "../assets/img/details/15/3.jpg",
          "desc": "Description 3"
        },
        { 
          "url": "../assets/img/details/15/4.jpg",
          "desc": "Description 4"
        }
    ],
    "header": "../assets/img/paramount-logo.svg",
    "behance": "https://www.behance.net/gallery/26358303/Avengers-Hulk-Desktop-WallPaper-Design"
  }
]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Sonam, thanks. This was what I thought I needed to do. I have reconstructed the object and I am getting this Syntax Error: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 495 - any ideas why?

Comment: Cool! Few questions: Can you share more of your code, so I can see where that error is coming from? Is this a raw JSON file that you're reading using fs, or how are you trying to access the data? Are you using either JSON.parse or JSON.stringify?

Comment: I have set the key value to path, not url

Comment: Hi, sure. I am accessing the json file using: 

`$http.get('app/resources/v1/projects/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').success(function (details) {`

so essentially, this looks for the params.id (a number) and then looks for a json file with the same name - the object you see above is what is then displayed using angularjs' ng-repeat in most cases or a loop to capture the url to a header image which is bound to the scope in the controller.

what code would you like me to send over?

Comment: a quick question, would I need to apply this edit to all objects to test? Or can I play with one until I get it to work? Or is this an issue within my controller?

Comment: I've added the controller code to the main question.

Comment: Cool, I'll look things over!

Comment: This is an invalid JSON: "url" and "desc" need to be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: got it! thank you Ivan and Sonam! how do I finish this off as the suggestion plus, sharp eye were the route to making this work!

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the typo check, Ivan! Glad things worked out, Ben!